# Стоит ли проверять коллекцию на наличие элементов до вызова цепочки асинхронных функций?

Tags: c#, оптимизация, async-await

Не нашёл подходящей темы, может плохо искал, но тем не менее. Может кто-то копал такую тему. Вот есть высоконагруженное приложение и хочется его оптимизировать по возможности. В частности есть в нём такие фрагменты кода:

```
{
    var items = GetItemsFromSomethere();
    await SomeAsyncFunction(items);
    // ...
}

async Task SomeAsyncFunction(ICollection<T> items)
{
    var filteredItems = await SomeAsyncFilter(items);
    await AnotherAsyncFunction(filteredItems);
    // и т.д., там и дальше могут ещё быть цепочки асинхронных вызовов
}
```

Так вот вопрос такой. Велики ли накладные расходы при вызове всех этих асинхронных функций - ведь там создаётся `state machine` на каждый вызов и т.д.
При этом я точно знаю, что часто бывают случаи, когда `SomeAsyncFunction` возвращает пустую коллекцию, да и вызывается она довольно часто и можно было бы избежать вызова всей этой цепочки асинхронных функций, просто проверив что коллекция пустая перед вызовом функции.

```
{
    var items = GetItemsFromSomethere();
    if(items.Count > 0)
    {
        await SomeAsyncFunction(items);
    }
    // ...
}

async Task SomeAsyncFunction(ICollection<T> items)
{
    var filteredItems = await SomeAsyncFilter(items);
    if(filteredItems.Count > 0)
    {
        await AnotherAsyncFunction(filteredItems);
        // и т.д., там и дальше могут ещё быть цепочки асинхронных вызовов
    }
}
```

Вроде и можно было бы так сделать везде по коду не задумываясь, ну а вдруг это ничего не даёт, так зачем усложнять и раздувать код какими-то лишними конструкциями.
Хотелось бы понять - **сэкономлю я что-то при таком подходе хотя бы теоретически или нет**?
Конечно, это будет зависеть от того, как часто коллекция бывает пустой, насколько длинные цепочки асинхронных функций и т.д., но хотя бы примерно и в общих чертах хотелось бы осознать тему.
И второе - **может есть какой-то синтаксический сахар, который позволил бы делать такую проверку** не перегружая код лишними конструкциями (в случае если такую проверку лучше и правда добавить в код)?
Спасибо.

P.S. Что касается синхронных функций, там я так понимаю расходы на лишний вызов функции с пустой коллекцией будут не так уж велики - положить ссылку на коллекцию в стек, да вызвать функцию. Всё-таки не `state machine`, попроще дело. Но если и насчёт синхронных функций есть какие-то рецепты на тему, с удовольствием их послушаю.

**Update:** Исправил `void` на `Task`, добавил `var` - писал пост по памяти, был не прав. И насчёт того, что самая быстрая проверка - это через `items.Count != 0` - совершенно верно было написано в исчезнувшем ответе, просто мне сама форма такой проверки кажется не такой красивой, как `items.Any()`. Но для оптимизации, видимо, придётся сделать именно так, если решу всё же поставить проверки. Тем более, что я проверил код - для `ICollection` всё-равно придётся проверять именно через `Count`, нет у него `Any()`.

Comment: Интересно, куда делся второй ответ (в нём были рациональные мысли, но я не успел ничего на него ответить). И кто и за что минусует вопрос и ответы...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге сам провёл примитивный бенчмарк, и получилось в общем как и ожидалось - эффект есть, но заметен он только на большом количестве выполнений такого кода.

Проверял, выполняя параллельно через `Task.WhenAll` 1,000,000 (миллион) Task-ов с цепочкой async/await, практически ничего не делающих, а просто передающих друг-другу управление (как это и будет в случае пустой коллекции).

Время выполнения в случае всегда пустой коллекции:

- c проверкой пустая ли коллекция (и дальше код не выполняем): 2 секунды.
- без проверки на размер коллекции: 2.5 секунды.
- без проверки на размер и с добавленным foreach (по пустой коллекции!) внутри методов: 2.7 секунды.

Ну то есть некоторый эффект всё же есть, но заметен он при выполнении очень большого количества задач и на сугубо всегда пустой коллекции.

Далее немного усложнил условия. Теперь в 50% случаев коллекция пустая, а в 50% там 100 элементов и они там внутри функций просто добавляются через foreach в новый список и возвращаются.

Естественно, время выполнения теста в целом возросло и эффект ещё более размазался:

- с проверкой на пустоту коллекции: 5 секунд
- без проверки: 5.2 секунды

В общем, некоторой экономии ресурсов таким образом можно достигнуть, но всё будет зависеть от соотношения количества пустых/не пустых коллекций на входе и от того, насколько тяжёлые вычисления выполняются с коллекциями внутри функций. Сильно много таким образом явно не удастся сэкономить.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, только профилирование кода может дать точный ответ.
Всё остальное - гадание на картах.

---

Вообще, добавление такой проверки может сломать код.

```
if(items.Any())
{
    filteredItems = await SomeAsyncFunction(items);
}
```

Если коллекция items пустая, то SomeAsyncFunction не будет вызвана. Но, возможно, она выполняла какое-то важное действие даже при наличии пустой коллекции. Побочный эффект это плохо, но всё же...

А если мы знаем внутреннее устройство SomeAsyncFunction и знаем, что её можно безопасно исключить, то это идёт вразрез с хорошими практиками программирования. С объектами нужно обращаться как с чёрными ящиками. Мы не обязаны знать их устройство.

Хотя, конечно, когда речь идёт о высоконагруженном коде, то хорошие практики и паттерны уходят на второй план.

Comment: Устройство функций я знаю и побочных эффектов нет. Какая-то работа производится функциями только в случае, когда передаются именно какие-то новые элементы. Иначе бы я и не пытался это оптимизировать. :)